# How to fix when cross icon is shown on place of date picker icon in firefox?

Tags: reactjs

The solution I found is installing Date picker plugin in react (npm install rc-datetime-picker) and using it on place of input html field having default date picker.
I cannot possibly go with this solution because I will have to make changes to every existing date picker in the project.

can you'll help me get a better solution to my problem.

```
     <Input style ={{width:165, fontFamily:"Arial,sans-serif", fontSize:"13px",fontFamily:'Arial,sans-serif',margin:" 0px 0px 0px 20px"}}
          type="date"
          placeholder="Enter Verification Date"
          value={r.doneDateAdminDisplay==null?"2020-01-01":r.doneDateAdminDisplay}
          min="2020-01-01"
          max={currentDate}
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
          onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
          onChange={(e) =>
              this.onDoneDateChange(e, index, r.subCategoryID, r.implementationStatus)
              
          }
          readOnly={localStorage.getItem("userRole") == USER_ROLE.KLISM ? true : false}
        />
```

Comment: Please share code and/or screenshots of your UI, so that people here can understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: basically cross icon (x) is shown on the place of date picker icon in firefox.